# No plugin found for prefix 'heroku' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: maven, tomcat, heroku

i am trying to deploy a maven java application on heroku using eclipse JEE.
But when i run i got this error

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'heroku' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\menna.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

this is my Pom.xml file

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
<exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>

<plugins>

  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.6</version>
  </plugin>

   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
       <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>


  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
    <appName>young-anchorage-8143</appName>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>


    </configuration>
  </plugin>


</plugins>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the error, it is not listed in the plugin groups, but you can force the plugin prefix mapping adding this to your local `settings.xml`.

```
<pluginGroups>
  <pluginGroup>com.heroku.sdk</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

I found the plugin group URL checking its last version page, which today is [2.0.7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.heroku.sdk/heroku-maven-plugin/2.0.7), and found that it is available in central repo, but it seems was not deployed to default plugins group. You can do the same if you ever run in this problem again with other plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Add heroku plugin to your pom.xml under plugins. Also make sure that your packaging is set to war. For more information check heroku's web [sit](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)e

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.16</version>
     </plugin>
```

To make it remote use:

heroku git:remote -a "app_name"